# thymeleaf bind file to object

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

i am trying to bind multiple files to an object as a byte array, but thymeleaf instead it bind only file names as a byte array. How can i catch file in controller? or bind file bytes?

Html:

```
<form th:action="@{/add}" th:object="${testObject}" method="post">
<span>add key</span>
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" th:field="*{privatekey}" type="file" name="file">
<span>add key</span>
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" th:field="*{publickey}" type="file" name="file">
<button type="submit">Seve</button>
```

testObject like:

```
public class TestObject {
...
@Column(name = "privatekey")
private byte[] privatekey;

@Column(name = "publickey")
private byte[] publickey;
}
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/add")
    public String singleFileUpload(@ModelAttribute("testObject") TestObject testObject,
                               RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
                               Principal principal) {

    testObjectService.save(testObject);
    return "redirect:test/page";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two changes you need to do:

1. Add `enctype` to `form`  element and update the `form` as shown below:

```
<form th:action="@{/handle-file-upload}" th:object="${fileObj}" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <span>add key</span>
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" th:field="*{file1}" type="file">
    <span>add key</span>
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" th:field="*{file2}" type="file">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

When you are using `th:field` you dont need to provide the `name` attribute because it will be created by Thmeleaf using the `th:field` name.

2. Update your `TestObject` class to change the type of `privatekey` and `publickey` to be of type `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile`  this way you will get the file bytes as well as other metadata of the file like original file name, content type.

Comment: Thank you, solution work. But i had to get the Entity DTO because the hibernate did not want save MultipartFile.

Comment: You can try with `byte[]` instead of `MultiPartFile` as well and see if it works.